# how to match both sitemap.xml and sitemap.xml.gz in nginx location and pass

Tags: regex, nginx, nginx-location

In nginx how would you match both `sitemap.xml` and `sitemap.xml.gz` but also return the match to proxy_pass:

```
location ~ ^/sitemap.(xml|xml\.gz);
  proxy_pass: "http://localhost/sitemap/sitemap.$1"
```

This only matches `sitemap.xml` **not** `sitemap.xml.gz`

**EDIT 1**

```
location ~ ^/sitemap.(.*)$;
  proxy_pass: "http://localhost/sitemap/sitemap.$1"
```

Matches will return a 200 on `sitemap.xml` and `sitemap.xml.gz` but will also try and proxy pass other unwanted requests.

Answer (score 1):

This answers my issue:

```
location ~ ^/sitemap.(xml|xml\.gz)$
    proxy_pass: "http://localhost/sitemap/sitemap.$1"
```